# Atmega328p clock and safe operation zone

Tags: atmega328, arduino-pro-mini

im not used to write in english but i hope you guys can understand. I have some doubts about using the arduino pro mini 3v3@8Mhz

- I know its possible to change the clock to 1 MHz with the fuses easily by setting CKDIV8 to '0'. But i dont understand if its possible to divide the internal 8 MHz clock to intermediate values like 4 MHz and 2 MHz.
- I know i can divide the clock with program running. The problem is i would like to run the arduino with a voltage less than 2,4V and arduino will start at 8MHz(out of safe operation area) for later change the clock to 4MHz(inside of safe operation area). Is there another way by software to always be in the safe zone ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just let CKDIV8 set (it just sets system clock prescaler to /8). And you can set different system clock prescaler later.

For changing system clock prescaler you need:

```
#include <avr/power.h>
```

And:

```
clock_prescale_set(clock_div_2); // possible values are clock_div_1 ... clock_div_256
```

Just don't forget that millis, delays and basically everything based on F_CPU might be slower/faster when prescaler gets changed.